# I need to create a special rule on my firewall with all the IP addresses from Facebook (Akamai included).... where I can get those IPs?

Tags: firewall, ip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get **all** IP addresses of a domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/191931/how-to-get-all-ip-addresses-of-a-domain)

Need this data to create a special rule, and I need to know if they change frequently or not. Somebody told me that they have a dedicated IP range on Akamai.

Thanks.

Comment: If you intend to block or allow connections to/from Facebook, you should know that you'll also be blocking/allowing thousands of other sites that use Akamai.

Answer (score 6):

There is no reasonable way you're going to be able to block facebook (or any other large website for that matter) purely at the IP level. You're going to be constantly adding and removing IPs, likely on a daily basis.

This is the job for a proxy, where you can properly block sites at the URL level and not have to worry about what IP addresses are behind them.

Comment: FWIW, we use Akamai and we get "new Edge server notifications" nearly weekly.

Comment: @KyleSmith - good to know. I'm sure it's safe to say that facebook itself also has a fair amount of flux in their public IP addressing as well.

Comment: Actually, there is a reasonable way: IP blocks.  Large companies like Facebook often contract out dedicated IP blocks and operate their own networks.  You can use http://whois.arin.net to search for 'facebook' and find out their directly assigned IP space and what they sublease from others as a customer.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to block facebook do it at the DNS level or use a web proxy to filter the content.